# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'product' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Error when i run the code:

[image: Error when i run the code]

```
export const cartReducer = (state = {cartItems:[]}, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            const item = action.payload;
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product );
            if(existItem){
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x)=>
                    x.product === existItem.product ? item:x),
                };
            }else{
                return{...state, cartItems:[...state.cartItems, item]};
            }
            default:
                return state;
    }
};


export const addToCart = (productId, qty) =>async (dispatch, getState) =>{
    const {data} = await Axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`);
    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            name: data.name,
            image: data.image,
            price: data.price,
            countInStock: data.countInStock,
            product: data._id,
            qty,
        },
    });
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

Comment: You don't have defined x anywhere. Seems your X should be the data._id got from exios

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at your `item` constant, wich comes from `action.payload`. It seems it's content may be null. That would make it so calling `item.product` inside `find` results in that **cannot read property 'product' of null** error.